# SwiftUI and tvOS: adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused

Tags: swiftui, tvos

How do you get the same focus effect in SwiftUI for images as you can with UIKit? I see you can use the card button style and it does provide motion effects but not the parallax that `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` provides.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("tapped")
        } label: {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "Image-URL"))
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.card)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the focus effects in UIKit that you refer to? Pinch to zoom?

Comment: Focus and Parallax https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/overview/focus-and-parallax/

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is pretty old, but I ran into the same problem and found that wrapping your UIImageView in a UIViewRepresentable works just fine.